# How to display individual feature popup on mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've got a map and have created a feature layer like this:

```
window.map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.wefk232sm')
    .setView([homeLatitude, homeLongitude], initialZoom);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// Pass features to the map
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

The geoJson object looks like this:

```
var geoJson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
        {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
            title: name,
            other: "text",
            'marker-color': '#54a743',
            'stroke': '#428334',
            url: link
        },
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
        }
    ]
};
```

What I'm trying to do is open the popup relating to a particular feature from, say the `name` on the `geoJson.features[0].properties` object, but I can't work out how to do this.

I can access it on click with this:

```
myLayer.on('click', function(e) {
    e.layer.openPopup();
});
```

Mapbox is v1.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to grab `properties.title`, for example, with the following

```
myLayer.on('click', function(e) {
    var title = e.layer.feature.properties.title;
    // do something with the title
});
```